# What is the sequence of points whose union covers $A = (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to wrap my head around totally bounded sets, and whether open and closed sets can be totally bounded.

For the set $A = (0,1)$ to be totally bounded, we require that for:

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists $ finite $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n \in A$ such that:

$A \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^n B_\epsilon(a_i)$

So for a given $\epsilon$, would we just make sure to choose two $a_m, a_M$ such that $d(a_m,0) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $d(a_M, 1) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ ?

Then, since $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\frac{\epsilon}{2}>1$, we can have $n$ such elements that totally bound $A$?

Am I on the right track? Does this hold for more general spaces outside of $\mathbb{R}$, and do we need some other properties (completeness etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be such that $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$. Then for $(0,1)$, the $n-1$ many points

$\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \frac{3}{n},\ldots, \frac{n-1}{n} \in A$ show that $(0,1)$ is totally bounded for $\varepsilon$.

This is quite specific for $\Bbb R$ and its subsets. In complete metric spaces $A$ is totally bounded iff $\overline{A}$ is compact, so many open sets can be totally bounded in such spaces. Completeness is not necessary as $\mathbb{Q}$ is not and $A=(0,1) \cap \Bbb Q$ can be shown totally bounded by the same proof...

Comment: By $\bar A$ do you mean the closure of $A$ ?

Comment: @codenoob indeed. A common notation.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and elegant ansewr.